# Ajax JSON SUMIF an array contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way in jQuery I can add the `SUM` of all JSON objects containing `BC` as the value of the client property? I am having trouble finding a solution on this I have tried this:

```
[
  {
    client: "BC",
    users: "PHIL",
    levels: "EAST",
    SUM: "32,600.00"
  },
  {
    client: "BC",
    users: "PHIL",
    levels: "EAST",
    SUM: "12,600.00"
  },
  {
    client: "AQ",
    users: "PHIL",
    levels: "WEST",
    SUM: "20,600.00"
  },
  {
    client: "AQ",
    users: "PHIL",
    levels: "WEST",
    SUM: "16,600.00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter, map and reduce as follows:

```js
var items = [{"client": "BC", "users": "PHIL", "levels": "EAST", "SUM":"32,600.00"},
      {"client": "BC", "users": "PHIL", "levels": "EAST", "SUM": "12,600.00"},
      {"client": "AQ", "users": "PHIL", "levels": "WEST", "SUM": "20,600.00"},          
      {"client": "AQ", "users": "PHIL", "levels": "WEST", "SUM": "16,600.00"}];

var sum = items.filter(item => {
    // get only ones with client property equals to 'BC'
    return item.client === "BC";
  }).map(item => {
    // parse SUM property values removing the commas and convert them to int
    return parseInt(item.SUM.replace(/,/g, ""));
  }).reduce((a, b) => {
    // sum 
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a faster way to do this typeof filter?